# Reading Excel Sheet with OleDb

Tags: c#, excel, oledb

I am trying to read an excel sheet through Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0. I followed a tutorial and write the code and deployed it. It was working fine but now after a long time we changed the server and now when I deployed the old code to the new server its giving me an error "The 'Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0' provider is not registered on the local machine."

I really dont remember what I did last time to make it running. I have tried alot of things but nothing worked.

I cant use any other dll because we dont have office installed on the server. Can any one please guide me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0' is a 32bit driver. If you compile your application with the AnyCPU as Platform target and deploy your application on a 64bit OS then your code is executed as 64bit code. In this context you are not able to reference a 32bit driver like OleDb.4.0.

Your best option is to recompile your application for x86 as target Platform and then your application will run as 32bit code that will be run without problem on a 64bit system and you will be able to use the 32bit OleDb.4.0.

If this is not possible then you should download the [Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255) in the 64bit version and install it on the target server. Also remember to change your connection string to

```
 string conString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" + 
                    "Data Source=path_to_your_excel_file.xls;" + 
                    "Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=YES\"";
```

Comment: Steve Thanks for reply, I have just installed Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable. And When I run the web again I got this error "Could not find installable ISAM."

Comment: Problem is I cant compile the app because I have hosted only source code files no dlls.

Comment: Double the quote around the extended properties?

Comment: just added them now another new message :) "Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 119"

Comment: for better understanding here  is my code string oleConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source="+ newFilePath +";Extended Properties\"Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=2\"";

Comment: Missing = between `Extended Properties=\"Excel...`?

Comment: By the way, you could also use single quotes instead of double quotes around the Extended Propeties settings

Comment: now I am getting "External table is not in the expected format." but file's extension is xls

Comment: Extesion xls doesn't automatically means that the file format is Excel 2003. You could try to use Extended Properties='Excel 12.0.....' Or other options listed here at [connectionstrings.com](http://www.connectionstrings.com/excel-2007)

Comment: thanks dude I think file is corrupted I will figure it out my self thanks alot for your support :)

Answer (score 1):

download and install it from: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255